# Python won't accept two same strings as the same

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, comparison, string-comparison

I'm quite a newcomer to Python and I am stuck in the following situation:

I want to hash a password and compare it with the masterhash. Unfortunately Python doesn't accept them as the same:

```
import hashlib
h=hashlib.sha512()
username='admin'
username=username.encode('utf-8')
h.update(username)
hexdigest=h.hexdigest()
hlist=open("database.txt")#masterhash
lines=hlist.readlines()
userhash=lines[0]#masterhash in line 0
if userhash == hexdigest: # it doesent accept them as the same
        text = "True"
else:
        text="False"
```

I already checked the objectypes: both string

The hash, both times:

> c7ad44cbad762a5da0a452f9e854fdc1e0e7a52a38015f23f3eab1d80b931dd472634dfac71cd34ebc35d16ab7fb8a90c81f975113d6c7538dc69dd8de9077ec

I really don't understand the problem.

Comment: yes             c7ad44cbad762a5da0a452f9e854fdc1e0e7a52a38015f23f3eab1d80b931dd472634dfac71cd34ebc35d16ab7fb8a90c81f975113d6c7538dc69dd8de9077ec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
lines = hlist.readlines()
```

Each value in this list will have a trailing newline (which you may not notice when `print`ing). Make sure you `strip` that off.

```
userhash = lines[0].strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

`readlines()` returns lines with newlines at their ends.  You are comparing "A" with "A\n".  Try this:

```
if userhash.strip() == hexdigest
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `readlines()` you get a list of the lines with the new line character at the end of each line, you can do one of two options:

**Option #1:**

```
lines = hlist.readlines()
userhash = lines[0].rstrip()
```

**Option #2:**

```
lines = hlist.read().splitlines()
userhash = lines[0]
```